# How to force a file path to be relative to the file it is in?

Tags: python, flask

I have this structure:

```
root/
  A.py
  test.txt
  module/
    __init__.py
    B.py
```

This is A.py

```py
import B
```

This is B.py

```py
with open('../test.txt'):
    pass
```

If I run this from the `root/`

```
python A.py
```

I get

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../text.txt'

But changing the path in `B.py` to `test.txt` works.

Now, I think it makes sense to me why. Clearly once in the context of `A.py` as our `__main__`, referencing `../test/txt` is relative to `A.py`, not `B.py`. How do I make it do what I need it to? That is, I want to reference the file relative to `B.py` and I want it to work no matter where I call it from.

PS: `A.py` is actually my Flask `app.py`

PPS: I don't want to just leave it as `test.txt` because I have a notebook

```
root/
  dev/
    notebook.ipynb
```

which imports B via

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')
import B
```

Comment: provide the file path from the root not from the subfile, i.e provide file path in reference to `A.py`

Comment: I suppose this would impost some structural changes though no? Like who I delegate the full responsibility of that functionality to.

Comment: then you can do is keep a sep .py file having file name and there path in it as `file_1 = file.txt` , make the path in referece to the running file ir `a.py` and from this .py file load the file and add the running file path to it as `file_full_path = os.path.join('root path', 'relative path')` and you can use this way to rganise all file and use in your codebase

Comment: @sahasrara62 thanks very much! You've been helpful enough already but if you have any links to examples please do add them.

Comment: JUST added a sample codebase, cant find the link where i read this way , but this is for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python by default adds some buildin values to the global namespace. `__file__` is a string representing the path of the file.

Example from [pep-3147/#file](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#file):

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.__file__
'foo.py' 
>>> # baz is a package
>>> import baz
>>> baz.__file__
'baz/__init__.py'
```

Using pathlib to navigate you can then get the module that holds B.py and specify a path relative to the module.

```
# B.py
from pathlib import Path

module = Path(__file__).parent
with open(module / "../test.txt"):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Is this a standard thing to do? Do I have a standard problem? Or am I generally doing things weirdly for some other reason?

Comment: @AlexanderSoare If the same code can get called in multiple ways, relative paths can break down. I think this is the best way to deal with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

file structure

```
root
├── A.py
├── documents
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── __init__.py
│   
├── files.py
├── module
    ├── B.py
    ├── __init__.py
```

content of A.py

```
from module.B import  func_read
from files import  file1
import os

running_file_path, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))

file_to_read = os.path.join(running_file_path, file1)
result = func_read(file_to_read)
print(result)
```

content of `file1.txt`

```
THIS IS a sample dcoument
```

content of `B.py`

```
import os


def func_read(file):
    if file is None or not os.path.isfile(file):
        return  "invalid file path or no file found"
    data = None
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    return  data
```

content of `file.py`

```
import os
from documents import document_path

file1 = os.path.join(document_path, 'file1.txt')
```

content of `documents/__init__.py`

```
import os
document_path = 'documents'
```

you can save the documents name in the file.py and save all document in document folder

all you need to load the document by there name from the file.py in different python files.
i have added document folder path in **init** file so if it is refactored or moved else where you need to change the
documnet folder path there relative to the folder and rest thing can be work somth.

NOTE: THIS IS A SIMPLE APPROACH YOU CAN ORGANISE YOUR PROJECT LIKE YOU WANT